# Remove Pictures Entry from Start Menu

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I want to remove the **Pictures** item from the topmost section of the Windows-7 Start Menu, but there is no option to do so in the *Tasbar and Start Menu Properties* dialog.

Expected:

[image]

Actual:

[image]

There are options to remove the other items (recorded tv, music, videos, etc.), and the option is present in the registry (`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartMenu\StartPanel\MyPics\Hide\CheckedValue=dword:0`), but it just doesn’t reflect in the Start Menu (**Pictures** is still shown while the others are removed).

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? Could it be a bug? (It's strange that only this one Start Menu item is broken.)

Comment: Looks like a bug/limitation to me.  What happens if you change from Windows Classic theme to Windows Standard under the Appearance control panel?

Comment: @Mikel, nope, the entry is still in the Start Menu and the option is still absent from the dialog box. (Yes, Windows is up-to-date.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't personally vouch for it (as I have not tried it), but it looks like [Ultimate Windows Tweaker](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-v2-a-tweak-ui-for-windows-7-vista) can do that, and more.

Comment: Well it didn’t fix the absence of the **Pictures** option in the dialog, and it reset all of the items to be links instead of menus like I had, but it did in fact remove the **Pictures** item from the Start Menu. It’s not a complete solution, but it accomplishes my original goal of removing it. (Now I just need to run ProcMon to figure out what changes and API calls UWT makes to accomplish that.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I untick "Don't display this item" under Pictures it does what it says.

This may sound dumb, but make sure you apply any changes before closing down the window.

Comment: Look at the screenshot again; there are NO options for **Pictures** at all.

Comment: Weird. Have you tried setting everything back to default settings?

Comment: Yes, it does not fix it. Besides, the dialog is just an interface for changing the options in the registry. Like I said, the registry entry in question is already present and set to not show the **Picture** item, but the Start Menu is ignoring it. Someone/something broke my Start Menu. `:-D`